# plot pins on MKMapView around 10 kms from current location

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, mkmapview

I have an `MKMapView` & I am using `PinAnnotation` for plotting the pins on `MKMapView`.
I have a local database which contains the `latitude` & `longitude` of thousands of locations. I want to plot the pins around 10 kms from current location on `MKMapView`, when the application is launched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I done it using the following way -

1) First found the current `latitude` & `longitude` using the `delegate` method of `MKMapView`(`didUpdateUserLocation`).

2) Found the distance from the current location with the location stored in my local DB in KM.

3) If `distance <=10 Kms`, then plot `pin`, else do nothing.

Answer (score 2):

It depends what your database. A simplistic way would be to work out the longitude difference for 10km (it is different at the equator and near the north pole) and the latitude difference for 10km, then search your database for everything between maxLat and minLat and maxLong and minLong. That gives you items in a rectangle but it's a start. From there you could cycle through every result, make it a CLLocation and check it is within 10km using [distanceFromLocation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocation/distanceFromLocation%3a).